# White Screen when running Graphics Diagnostics in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, graphics, directx

I'm unable to run the visual studio graphics debugger on my C++ DirectX project.  I can run the project fine in regular debug mode, but when I attempt to use the graphics debugger, I only get a white screen.

I took a look at my DirectX Panel and it appears that I have a few options such as message settings which are unavailable.  Could this have anything to with my problem?

[image: Properties]

Also, I have tested this project on another computer and I was able to successfully run the graphics debugger.  So, I think the problem has something to with settings on my computer and not the necessarily the project itself.

Comment: The dialog is all dimmed out because you haven't selected any programs to debug yet.  Click Edit List.  Doubtful it has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: What's your OS version? driver version? hardware? do you have latest updates for VS?

Comment: I was using visual studios 2013 and I guess I didn't have the latest update.  I updated to Update 4 and I was able to get the debugger to work.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I didn't have the latest Visual Studio 2013 Update. I updated to Update 4 and I was able to get the debugger to work.